# Django through relationship

Tags: django

I have a Person class, a Project class and Contract class. One project leads to a contract where people are hired. Now I want a class with people related with their contracts so I create another class, ContractStaff, in order to implement a through relationship:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = CharField
    adress = CharField
    #contract_staff is a list of all the Contracts a single Person object has
    contract_staff = ManyToManyField(Contract, through = 'ContractStaff')

class ContractStaff(models.Model):
    person = ForeignKeyField(Person)

class Contract(models.Model):
    id_ref = IntegerField
    starting_date = DateField
    ending_date = DateField
    contract_staff = ForeignKey(ContractStaff)
    project = OneToOneField(Project)

class Project(models.Model):
    title = CharField
    id_ref = IntegerField
           ...
```

The thing is that I've seen in other examples that is the intermediate class which has the two FK, in my example is the Contract class which has one of them, linking the other two classes. As a ContractStaff could have many Contracts and one Contract has only one ContractStaff I guess the FK field should go in the Contract class. Am I wrong? Is this model correct?

Comment: I don't think this makes much sense, but it's hard to tell because it's not clear what the classes are. What is an instance of Staff? Is that a staff member? Similarly, what is a ContractStaff instance? And what is the many-to-many relationship actually denoting?

Comment: I've edited, I hope it is clearer.

Comment: Not really. Why do you need ContractStaff at all? The ForeignKey could go straight from Contract to Person, in which case `person.contract_set.all()` would be the list of all the contracts a single person has.

Answer (score 2):

A `ManyToManyField` is implemented by means of a through table that has two foreign keys, to the connected tables. If you don't have that, then what you have is not a many to many field.

For instance, if you want to make it so that one Person can be connected to several Contracts, and that a Contracts can be connected to several Persons, then you need a ManyToManyField. It would be implemented with one row in the through table per connection between a person and a contract, so every connection would have exactly 1 person and 1 contract, hence the two foreign keys.

A through model is used if you also want some extra information on the connection (say, one Person is connected to a Contract as "project leader", and another as "programmer"), then you can make the model implicit and put a field on that model for that role.

What you have is not a ManyToManyField.

Edit: specifically, if a Contract can have one ContractStaff, and a ContractStaff can have one Person, then there's a many-to-one relation from Contract to ContractStaff to Person, not a ManyToMany.

Comment: I saw, hence the edit. The point stands: what you have is not a many to many relationship.